# show div from bottom

Tags: html, css, display

i'am trying to update my portfolio to bootstrap 4. Here's my case :

I want to display a div from bottom to top on hover at the img. See my pic to understand please.[image: Hover display]

Which technique may i use to do this right ?

i use this code but the div stay hidden cause of 'display:none'

Any idea to do this in the best way please ?

```
     <style>
     #container {
     bottom: 0;
     display: none;
     position: fixed;
     width: 15%;
     }

     #inner {
     background-color: #F0F0F0 ;
     border: 1px solid #666666 ;
     border-bottom-width: 0px ;
     padding: 20px 20px 500px 20px ; 
     }
     </style>
     var container = $( "#container" );


        // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
        $( "a" ).hover(
            function( event ){
                // Prevent the default event.
                event.preventDefault();

                // Toggle the slide based on its current
                // visibility.
                if (container.is( ":visible" )){

                    // Hide - slide up.
                    container.slideUp( 2000 );

                } else {

                    // Show - slide down.
                    container.slideDown( 2000 );

                }
            }
        );
                     <p>
                              <a href="#">Show Div With SlideDown()</a>
                      </p>

                  <div id="container">
                  <div id="inner">

                      my picture project

                   </div>
                   </div>
```

Comment: You aren't really asking a specific question, rather asking for someone to implement your design. My short answer would be: use pure CSS. No JS, but I cannot say more without actually doing the work for you...

Comment: Thank your for your answer. My question is mentionned on top : wich technique is the best to do this kind of display. The second one is : how to leave some pixels to display in the bottom like in the picture. I don't know how to do this instead of the display is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following snippet. You can position the different elements from within the menu, to have different rules for when the menu item is hover (using pure CSS).

You'll have to play with the styling, of course - this is just a POC of how you can make it using CSS.

Explanation: Position the menu items on the bottom, and within each item, place the content you want to show when it's hover. Then give a `:hover` rule for menu item, and within that element, select the content element to show (using either `display: block` or whatever method you like).

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

li .content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

li:hover .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      item1
      <div class="content">
           <h1>item1</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      item2
      <div class="content">
        <h1>item2</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I was searching for something very hard. I'am beginner in Webdesign. Thank you for your explanation.